# select input type to use database fields

Tags: php, html, database

How would I utilise my code for a select input type to use data within a database? I've got a connection to my datebase that works fine it terms of writing data and also retrieving data to a text box etc. Yet to workout how it works for a select type though.

Im currently using :

```
<select name="product" width="100" style="width: 245px">
    <option value="laptop">laptop</option>
    <option value="keyboard">keyboard</option>
</select>
```

How could I change my code so that when a user selects the drop down menu from the select it lists all options from a specific row in my products table?

Updated code:

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){

$choice = $_POST['product'];
}

 $query="SELECT * from loanproducts WHERE product = '$choice'";

 while($row = fetch_assoc($query)){

 echo $row[product];
  }
 endwhile;

if (isset($_POST['addloan'])):

$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$product=$_POST['product'];
$date_collected=$_POST['date_collected'];
$date_return=$_POST['date_return'];
$returned=$_POST['returned'];


$my_query="INSERT INTO loans VALUES ('','$username','$product','$date_collected','$date_return','$returned')";

$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);

if ($result):
            header ('location: homepage.php?confirm=New loan successfully  created');
        else :
            echo "<b>This didn`t work, error: </b>";
            echo mysqli_error($connection);
endif;

endif;
```

HTML:

```
<form method=post action="addloan.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="username"  autocomplete="off" size="30" value="<? php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" disabled>
<br><br>
<select name="product" width="100" style="width: 245px">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Product?</option>
    <option value="laptop">laptop</option>
    <option value="keyboard">keyboard</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="date" name="date_collected" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Collection Date?" size="30"> 
<br><br>
<input type="date" name="date_return" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Return Date?" size="30">
<br><br>
<select name="returned" width="100" style="width: 245px">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Returned?</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="addloan" value="Create Loan" >
</form>
```

Comment: you have to provide much more that this. you need to be aware of how a client can communicate with a server. please consider some tutorials on some very basic stuff in the internet, and feel free to come back again :)

Comment: use javascript or jquery ajax as client-side scripting

Comment: **A:** use a WHERE clause from values pulled from a POST/GET array / name attribute(s).

Comment: Not kicking for rep here, but I posted an answer some 20+ mins. ago with no response. You might have left, or what I posted did not work for you, or you don't know what to do with it. Your question has been unclear from the get go, so if mine didn't work, you will need to post your full code and which API used and database you're using here, if MySQL, MSSQL, ORACLE, other and connection API.

Comment: I'll just leave it for you then. ping me if something goes South.

Comment: @Fred-ii- apologies fred, I was away from desk. I have updated the code that I am currently using. let me know if your below answer remains the same based on my updated code, thanks

Comment: @Mucca019 Ah, I had a feeling about you having to leave (*Spidey sense tingled*); no worries ;-) Well, seeing what you posted for db stuff; you'd need another script for this, which is what my answer basically does. You just need to apply the appropriate `mysqli_*` functions for it. and you're welcome.

Comment: @Mucca019 Plus, seeing you have more than one `<select>` and additional inputs and that could be tricky if someone only chooses from one of them. Will all of those be required to be selected, including the inputs? if so, then you'd need to assign variables to each of the POST arrays, then use an additional `AND` or `OR` clause in `WHERE`, if that helps.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi fred, I've updated my code again, adding in your answer. Its breaking the page though - so I'm guessing i've done something wrong if you could take a look?

Comment: @Mucca019 you didn't connect with `$query="SELECT * from loanproducts WHERE product = '$choice'";` so that needs to read as `$query=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * from loanproducts WHERE product = '$choice'");` You also need to remove the `endwhile;` for that `while($row = fetch_assoc($query)){` and add quotes (maybe) `echo $row['product'];` - check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given no code to work with (consult my "footnotes"), this is the logic you can use.

Use a `WHERE` clause from values pulled from a POST/GET array and name attribute(s).

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">

<select name="product" width="100" style="width: 245px">
    <option value="laptop">laptop</option>
    <option value="keyboard">keyboard</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){

    $choice = $_POST['product'];

}
```

Query: N.B.: `query()` is an example here. Consult my "footnotes".

```
SELECT * FROM table where col_x = '$choice'
```

or actual columns:

```
$query = query($con, "SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 FROM table where col_x = '$choice'");
```

Then you would loop over results; `fetch_assoc()` is an example here. Consult my "footnotes".

```
while($row = fetch_assoc($query)){

    echo $row['col_1'] . " " . $row['col_2'] . " " . $row['col_3'];

}
```

**Footnotes:**

The API used to connect with is unknown, so you will need to escape that value and use the respective functions to connect/query with. As is the db schema being unknown.

- You will need to adjust accordingly.